# Is multicasting inherent to all ethernet systems?

Tags: multicast

Is multicasting inherent to every ethernet system?

What I am trying to do is send codes via ethernet to many devices  (without having to send the same 'message' to each device).  I am not familiar with the design of multicast systems, so forgive me if this is a lame question.  I do know there are IP ranges reserved for the use of multicasting, but does that mean if i set receiving devices to those IPs, they will all receive the same 'messages'?

Comment: The ideal application for multicast is time.  You can send it out and anyone interested can listen.  If you lose a packet once in a while its ok because you can get the next one.  Therefore you should see a big red flag when you notice that no time protocol uses multicast.

Answer (score 0):

The [IGMP wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol) page has a lot of good information.  Your question is a bit out of scope for stackoverflow.

Multicast uses IP, but I wouldn't say it's inherent to every ethernet system because all network infrastructure needs to be properly configured to allow IGMP subscription.

You do not **set** a client to the multicast IP.  Your client subscribes to the multicast ip, your router sees this subscription and passes it along to that device.  The wikipedia page will point you in the right direction, but as I said earlier, it's a bit outside the scope of Stack overflow.